# Applying for a Health and Social Care visa after the start date in the Certificate of Sponsorship

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, immigration, paperwork

Can I apply for UK skilled worker visa after the Certificate of Sponsorship (CoS) start date without the sponsor changing such date? Please help.

Comment: What's CoS?  The question is not clear even after working around the grammar errors.  Also it is a convention that words rendered in all capital letters constitutes shouting and it is not clear whether that would be necessary in this case.

Comment: What country are you asking about? You should add it as a tag

Comment: @C'estMoi It is never necessary to shout.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, providing you apply within 3 months of the date in your Certificate of Sponsorship.

Source: [UK visa sponsorship for employers](https://www.gov.uk/uk-visa-sponsorship-employers/certificates-of-sponsorship)

> When you assign the certificate to a worker, they must use it to apply for their visa within 3 months. They must not apply for their visa more than 3 months before the start date of the job listed on the certificate.